# How can I retrieve Firstname in my database?

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans

I have these codes

`DBCollection.java`

```
public LogInHandler userGreetName()
{
    LogInHandler login = new LogInHandler();
    String query = null;

    try
    {
        query = "SELECT First_Name FROM user_information WHERE Username = '"+login.getUsername()+"'";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        rs.next();
        login.setGreetName(rs.getString("First_Name"));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.toString());
    }
    return login;
}
```

On my `mainWindow.java` I have formWindowOpened event and contains the codes

```
DBCollection dbc = new DBCollection();
greetNameL.setText(dbc.userGreetName().getGreetName());
```

LogInHandler.java

```
public class LogInHandler extends ValidateLogin{
DBCollection dbc = new DBCollection();

private String username;
private String greetName;


public void setGreetName(String temp)
{
    greetName = temp;
}
public String getGreetName()
{
    return greetName;
}

public void setUsername(String temp)
{
    username = temp;
}

public String getUsername()
{
    return username;
}
```

I have `login.setUsername(usernameTF.getText());` in my `loginWindowGUI`

here's my problem.. I cant retrieve the First_Name column in my database.. it displays null. and is my WHERE condition in query is correct? help please..

Comment: +1 for the formatting.. hadn't seen such clean, formatted code in days..

Comment: can you debug it and see whats in login.username and ensure thats in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the way you've set your code exposes you to SQL injection.

```
query = "SELECT First_Name FROM user_information WHERE Username = '"+login.getUsername()+"'";
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
rs.next();
login.setGreetName(rs.getString("First_Name"));
```

Something like the below should do the same job as your code, but protect you from SQL injection.

```
query = "SELECT First_Name FROM user_information WHERE Username = ?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStatement.setString(1, login.getUsername());
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(query);
rs.next();
login.setGreetName(rs.getString("First_Name"));
```

I don't think that is what's causing your code not to work however. You need to give us more information.

Have you tried directly querying the DB with the following string?

```
SELECT First_Name FROM user_information WHERE Username = 'A user name that is definitely in the DB';
```

That should verify if your query is correct or not. If it works, then I would go into debug mode in Netbeans. Put a breakpoint before the following line

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

Check to see if login.username variable is populated. If that field is null, then your problem is there.